# What are good options for cloud storage of audit data? (written continuously, rarely queried)

Tags: aws, cloud

*Cross-post from StackOverflow as I expect it may get closed there because S.O is so nitpicky...*
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63432484/what-are-good-options-for-cloud-storage-of-audit-data-written-continuously-ra

I'm working on something which wants to store a lot of "audit record" style data. Such as "user created a thing", "user deleted a thing", "user had 27 things".
We want to store it in the cloud (AWS or possibly Azure). Ideally I'd like to use a cloud-native service such that I don't have to worry about things like scaling up server instances, sharding, etc.

This kind of data is mostly a continuous stream of writes, and every so often a big "report" style query where we summarize or count a large block of data over a given date range. We need to query individual records approximately never.

The go-to for "cloud database in AWS" seems to be DynamoDB, however the pricing model, and the articles I've been reading seem to imply it is designed for more of a transactional model. Writes are an order of magnitude more expensive than reads, which is the opposite to my use case.

Those of you with deep cloud knowledge - please: What service(s) would you use for storing this kind of data and running reports on it? Is DynamoDB a bad choice here?

Comment: Please do not cross post. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your requirements as (in order)

1. Store lots of records cheaply
2. Execute queries infrequently, insensitively to performance.

On AWS the cheapest bulk storage is S3. Other providers may be cheaper per GB (e.g. Backblaze) but you have to balance the stirage / egress costs. We'll get back to the format in a moment.

Now you need a way to read that data without ingesting  it all into another service. Data virtualization (DV) seems to be the answer here. If you're already paying for a DBMS which supports reading external data you may be able to piggy-back this infrequent workload on that service.

There are stand-alone data virtualization products such as Apache Calcite and AtScale. Installing one on a dedicated VM which is quiesced when unused should suffice.

The format used for the S3 files then depends on what the DV server supports. Ideally something compressed like Parquet. Failing that a structured format such as JSON, with a comprehensive dictionary to guide what lables to use.

I will note that Snowflake does not charge for storage over AWS's own price, only for compute, and can read JSON. This may be the best overall as a turn-key solution.